# JavaScript - Gmail API - Send email with attachment

Tags: javascript, email-attachments, gmail-api

I have been searching for this for weeks. I just want to be able to send an email *with* an attachment.

I've been able to send an email, text and html.

I can upload a document to google drive.

I assumed knowing these two things would enable me to reach my end goal, but I cannot for the life of me get an attachment to send through the gmail api.

This question very well may already be on stack overflow, but I have not seen any posts with **javascript** as the language. And the ones that were did not address sending an email with an attachment.

i dont care if it's through cors or through the gapi.client, i just need it to work.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: doesn't look like attachments have been incorporated into the js library yet but no reason you can't call the endpoint manually..

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads#resumable

Comment: i banged my head for a whole night to figure out the gmail api from their documentation and then switched to amazon ses which works like a charm with node mailer.

Comment: @PootieTang -- can you elaborate on "no reason you can't call the endpoint manually"

Comment: alls the library does is make AJAX requests to their endpoints, write some ajax to call the endpoint

Comment: Have you tried the suggested solution in this SO post - [GMAIL API for sending Email with attachment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31784167/gmail-api-for-sending-email-with-attachment)?

Comment: I wrote a [tiny module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gmail-api-create-message-body) for this a while back you might want to check out.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have achieved so far. I'm using the `gapi` client library.

So first you have to construct your emails properly, here's my working example, note that in between any part an empty line is required. You can add all parts into an array and use the `your_array.join('\r\n')` to construct the email.

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="your_boundary"
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: person1@gmail.com
To: person2@gmail.com
Subject: Test
Reply-To: person1@gmail.com
Date: Wed Jan 04 2017 10:47:11 GMT-0500 (EST)

--your_boundary
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<p>Boundary, multi attachs<br />
<em><strong>--<br />
With Regards</strong></em></p>

--your_boundary
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sort_asc.png"

YOUR_BASE64_ENCODED_DATA

--your_boundary
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sort_both.png"

YOUR_BASE64_ENCODED_DATA

--your_boundary
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sort_desc.png"

YOUR_BASE64_ENCODED_DATA

--your_boundary--
```

Then I'm using gapi's client to send the email; `sendMessage` is the function that gapi's online document provides. Before you send email, you need to **Base64URL** encode your email. I got the encode library from here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-base64

```
sendMessage = function(userId, email, callback) {
     var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
        'userId': userId,
        'resource': {
            'raw': email
        }
    });

    request.execute(callback);
}

sendMessage('me', Base64.encodeURI(email), function(resp) {
    if(resp.labelIds && resp.labelIds.indexOf('SENT') > -1) {
        console.log('Your email has been sent.');
    }else {
        console.log('Something went wrong');
    }
});
```