# Gmail API - Send attachment from Firebase Storage's URL

Tags: firebase, gmail, firebase-storage, gmail-api

Given some URL from Firebase Storage `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/example/etc`, how do I get the data from it in the web?

Moreover, this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31784167/gmail-api-for-sending-email-with-attachment) teaches how to send an attachment through the Gmail API (I am already being able to send an email, but struggling with sending an attachment together with it).

Which kind of data do I need to pass as told in the post (The author does not specify it) and how do I retrieve this data? I imagine it is some kind of string representing the bytes of the file, but I am unaware how to retrieve it given some URL (in this case Firebase Storage one)

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.