# How does the body of the request look like when making a call to gmail api for sending an email with attachment (multipart)?

Tags: email, gmail, angular5, gmail-api, rfc822

Google documentation gave an example as below:

POST /upload/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send?uploadType=multipart HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=foo_bar_baz
Content-Length: number_of_bytes_in_entire_request_body

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
  "id": string,
  "threadId": string,
  "labelIds": [
    string
  ],
  "snippet": string,
  "historyId": unsigned long,
  "payload": {
    "partId": string,
    "mimeType": string,
    "filename": string,
    "headers": [
      {
        "name": string,
        "value": string
      }
    ],
    "body": users.messages.attachments Resource,
    "parts": [
      (MessagePart)
    ]
  },
  "sizeEstimate": integer,
  "raw": bytes
}

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: message/rfc822

Email Message data
--foo_bar_baz--
If the request succeeds, the server returns the HTTP 200 OK status code along with any metadata:

HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": string,
  "threadId": string,
  "labelIds": [
    string
  ],
  "snippet": string,
  "historyId": unsigned long,
  "payload": {
    "partId": string,
    "mimeType": string,
    "filename": string,
    "headers": [
      {
        "name": string,
        "value": string
      }
    ],
    "body": users.messages.attachments Resource,
    "parts": [
      (MessagePart)
    ]
  },
  "sizeEstimate": integer,
  "raw": bytes
}

Can someone make a sample request body by looking at the above example?
I need to send an email with attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Based from [SO related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31784167/gmail-api-for-sending-email-with-attachment), the body request can be something like this:

```
var mail = [
  'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="foo_bar_baz"\r\n',
  'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n',
  'From: sender@gmail.com\r\n',
  'To: receiver@gmail.com\r\n',
  'Subject: Subject Text\r\n\r\n',

  '--foo_bar_baz\r\n',
  'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"\r\n',
  'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n',
  'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n',

  'The actual message text goes here\r\n\r\n',

  '--foo_bar_baz\r\n',
  'Content-Type: image/png\r\n',
  'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n',
  'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n',
  'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="example.png"\r\n\r\n',

   pngData, '\r\n\r\n',

   '--foo_bar_baz--'
].join('');

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?uploadType=media", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
                "Content-Type": "message/rfc822",
            },
            muteHttpExceptions: true,
            payload: mail
});
```

Here's also an [example code](https://ctrlq.org/code/20132-gmail-api-send-mail-attachments) from digital inspiration written by Amit Agarwal in Google Appscript.
This example shows how you can easily send email messages with file attachment using Gmail API.

Comment: I tried this format while sending request to /gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send and it worked fine for me. But its kind of workaround to send email with attachment. The google documentation says the mails with attachment has to be handled using /upload/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send .But for know i could able to send mail with single file attachment.